# Can I use the same key for SSH from different clients with the same username?

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, openssh, public-key

Situation: One server with SSH daemon. Multiple clients with the user `myUser` which should connect to the server via SSH. With password based authentication everything is fine.

Now I would like to migrate to public key authentication. On `workstation1` I generated a key (pair) and transfered the public key to the server utilizing `ssh-copy-id`. Public key authentication is working so far.

Now I checked `/home/myUser/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server. There is only one key present associated with `myUser@workstation1`. There is also an association to `myUser@workstation1` in `/home/myUser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on `workstation1`.

I want to connect to `myUser@server` from multiple clients (`myUser@workstation1`, `myUser@workstation2` ... , `myUser@workstationN`).

- **Can I use the same key from all of those clients? Must I remove the clients name `workstation1` from the key file or `authorized_keys` file? Does this have any security implications?**
- **Or should I better generate a separate key for every workstation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same key from each workstation.  Your workstation's name is part of the comment attached to the key, and should not prevent you from copying the key to another machine and using it there.

When *copying* the key, people recommend that you do this via a *secure* mechanism such as a detachable USB drive.  Just copying it directly over the network is subject to whatever limitations exist with that connection.

Further reading:

- [How to transfer my SSH keys to another machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/332510/how-to-transfer-my-ssh-keys-to-another-machine)
- [Easiest way to copy ssh keys to another machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4830/easiest-way-to-copy-ssh-keys-to-another-machine)

Comment: When using flash media like an SSD or USB stick to copy a private key, encrypt the key first, like in an encrypted zip or truecrypt volume. When you delete the plain key, the key will still exist on the drive, only the listing is removed.