# One SSH key for accessing the server from any operating system

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, ssh-keys

Can I generate one SSH key and then use this key to SSH server from any operating system like mac, windows, sunsolaris or linux command shell?

**UPDATE:**

1. I have a dedicated server and I may access it as a root from
   different Operating Systems
2. The server is not shared to any user. Will it be better to generate SSH key on server or client machines?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. This seems to be well-explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1027885/can-i-use-the-same-key-for-ssh-from-different-clients-with-the-same-username?rq=1), along with useful links describing different ways of copying existing keys to other machines.

Comment: That's the NORMAL thing to do!  It'd take a more effort and a little bit more knowledge to do use different keys for different operating systems/computers!  So you do the normal thing. You generate the public and private key,  keep the private key private.  Send the public key to those computers. Any ssh key explanation will tell you.

Comment: may I generate key on the server and then use it on any client machine?
OR I have to generate key on client machine and then transfer to server? Furthermore, I want to use this key to access root

Comment: In the general case it is best to generate the key on the client, because if the server is shared, another user could get access to the private key. Having one key per client isn't much more difficult and could be simpler to handle...

Comment: @xenoid I agree with one key per client but if there is one key identity on the server then I can not login to the server without key. How do I connect to the server to upload another key in this case?

Comment: You'll have to upload other public keys using the machines that already have their public key on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have access to the server?  so just create your keys on each client and manually add the PUBLIC key from each to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the host you wish to access.

to generate keys:
Linux:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Windows:
not sure if there is a better way, but I d/l putty tool and use

```
puttygen
```

Mac:

```
ssh-keygen
```

====
with linux you can copy your keys to the server using

```
ssh-copy-id root@<server_ip>
```

not sure how to do that under windows just ( should be a very quick google/SO search ) which is why I suggested adding your keys manually.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: my basic question is that can I generate one ssh key to use on all operating systems? This will be secure and better to have one key instead of different keys for different OS (2) I have bad experience as I generated one key in windows that work fine in windows environment but I am not able to use same key from centos 7

Comment: Ok.. so yes, you can, this is standard usage of ssh keys.You could even generate your keys on one box ( linux for eg ) and copy the private key to correct home/key folder on each system  and the public key to the server you wish to access...  but please be aware of the dangers of copying your private keys to different clients, there be dragons. but short answer... yes , you can

Comment: Thanks. Why my ssh created on windows environment not working on linux? This is what I cam here and afraid of

Comment: Hello its been some time sinve i generqted ssh keys on windows but if i remember correctly they ate formatted differently. Try to open both (linux and windows keys) in a text editor and compare to see the difference, dont edit the actual hash (long code) of the windows key but try to put it to the same as the linux key,  alternatively as i suggested copy your private key from linux  to the correct folder on your windows box, and you should be good to go..  (on mobile now so pls excuse formatting)